# Get element ID's on hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, events, jquery-animate

It were nice if someone could help. I created an animated menu. The only thing is that, in my JS, I repeat my code for all five buttons. I tried to get the id's from each html elements, to optimize my script, but it doesn't work. Please help. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="button-container">
            <a id="link-1" class="link" onclick="location='page1.html'; return false" href="http://Buttonname1">
                <!-- Image apparaissant au clic -->
                <img id="bottom-1-clicked" class="toggle-1" src="button58.gif">
                <!-- Image apparaissant au survol après disparition de l'image d'origine -->
                <img id="bottom-1" class="toggle-1" src="button59.gif">
                <!-- Image apparaissant au chargement de la page. Glisse vers la droite au survol puiq revient vers la gauche -->
                <img id="top-1" class="toggle-1" src="button55.gif">
                <span class="text-container">Buttonname1</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
            <a id="link-2" class="link" onclick="location='page2.html'; return false" href="http://Buttonname2">
                <img id="bottom-2-clicked" class="toggle-2" src="button58.gif" alt="">
                <img id="bottom-2" class="toggle-2" src="button59.gif" alt="">
                <img id="top-2" class="toggle-2" src="button55.gif" alt="">
                <span class="text-container">Buttonname2</span>
            </a>
        </div>      
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

> Here my JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() { 
        $('.link').hover(function(childs) {
            // Hovering the menu item, the first image slides to the right, discovering another image
            $(this.id).hover(function(){
                $(":nth-child(3)", this).attr('id').stop(true, false).animate({ left: 130 }, 300);
            });
            // On mouse leave, the image slides back to the left
            $(this.id).mouseleave(function(){
                $(":nth-child(3)", this).attr('id').stop(true, false).animate({ left: 0 }, 300);
            });
            // On click, the image changes, displaying a third image
            $(this.id).mousedown(function(){
                $(":nth-child(2)", this).attr('id').hide(50);
                $(":nth-child(1)", this).attr('id').show(50);
            });
        });
    }, 300 );
});
```

Comment: You should write your comments in english, so more people will understand

Comment: Your code seems very confused. Every 300ms you're binding another `hover` event handler, which itself has 3 other event handlers, including another `hover` handler. I'm not sure exactly what your goal is, but I can tell you that the logic right now is incorrect, and that your request to get the `id` of the element is not relevant as this is not how the code should be written. Can you please edit the question to include the all relevant HTML and CSS as well as a description of your goal.

Comment: Expanding on Rory's comments , using `$(this.id)` leaves out the `"#"` prefix needed for an id selector and is equivalent to `$('link-1')` which is looking for an element `<link-1></link-1>`. Your code is full of problems

Comment: Make the code runnable in a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry for the comments, I didn't realize there were in french, I changed them.

Here's how my script work:
The buttons contains 3 images. The first appears when loading the page. On hover, it slides to the right, discovering the second image.
Here, when the mouse leaves the button, the first images commes back, sliding to the left, or when clicking the button, the second image disapears, discovering a third image.

The first hover detect the ID of the button.

Here's the CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 130px;
    height: 194px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.button-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 39px;
}   
.text-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    font: 12px arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #990099;
    transform: translate(0, -65%);
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}       
.text-container:hover {
    color: #000000;
}
.text-container:active {
    color: #990099;
}
.toggle-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.toggle-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link").mouseover(function() {
    // Hovering the menu item, the first image slides to the right, discovering another image
    $(":nth-child(3)", this).stop(true, false).animate({
      left: 300
    }, {
      easing: "linear"
    }, 300);

    // On mouse leave, the image slides back to the left
    $("#" + this.id).mouseleave(function() {
      $(":nth-child(3)", this).stop(true, false).animate({
        left: 0
      }, {
        easing: "linear"
      }, 300);
    });

    // On click, the image changes, displaying a third image
    $("#" + this.id).mousedown(function() {
      $(":nth-child(2)", this).hide(50);
      $(":nth-child(1)", this).show(50);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 130px;
  height: 194px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 39px;
}

.text-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  font: 12px arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #990099;
  transform: translate(0, -65%);
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.text-container:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

.text-container:active {
  color: #990099;
}

.toggle-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.toggle-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="button-container">
      <a id="link-1" class="link" onclick="location='page1.html'; return false" href="http://Buttonname1">
        <!-- Image appearing on click -->
        <img id="bottom-1-clicked" class="toggle-1" src="[button58.gif][1]">
        <!-- Image appearing on hover, after the upper one disappears -->
        <img id="bottom-1" class="toggle-1" src="[button59.gif][1]">
        <!-- Image appearing when the page is loaded. The images slides to the right on  hover and slides to the left when mouse leaves it -->
        <img id="top-1" class="toggle-1" src="[button55.gif][1]">
        <span class="text-container">Buttonname1</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <a id="link-2" class="link" onclick="location='page2.html'; return false" href="http://Buttonname2">
        <img id="bottom-2-clicked" class="toggle-2" src="[button58.gif][1]" alt="">
        <img id="bottom-2" class="toggle-2" src="[button59.gif][1]" alt="">
        <img id="top-2" class="toggle-2" src="[button55.gif][1]" alt="">
        <span class="text-container">Buttonname2</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

I found a solution. It only one problem. When a button is clicked, the image changes and the new page open. But, when we return to the previous page by clicking the browser's button, the button doesn't return to it's initial state. That means, when the top image slides to the right, it displays the image normally display on click, instead of the one displayed by hovering.

Here is my new script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".link").mouseover(function() {
            // Hovering the menu item, the first image slides to the right, discovering another image
            $(":nth-child(3)", this).stop(true, false).animate({ left: 300 }, { easing: "linear" }, 300);
            
            // On mouse leave, the image slides back to the left
            $("#"+this.id).mouseleave(function(){
                $(":nth-child(3)", this).stop(true, false).animate({ left: 0 }, { easing: "linear" }, 300);
            });
        
             // On click, the image changes, displaying a third image
            $("#"+this.id).mousedown(function(){
                $(":nth-child(2)", this).hide(50);
                $(":nth-child(1)", this).show(50);
            });
        });
});
```